# Showing continous sequence of images in ImageView

Tags: android

I have a candle and flame as separate image views. When user taps on the flame, its drawable resource is set to transparent meaning the flame has blown off.

I also want to show smoke as the flame is blown off. For that I have some 21 images of black smoke which can be shown in quick sequence so that users sees it as smoke. Here is my code which hangs when the flame is tapped (R.drawable.smoke_22 is the transparent image for flame and R.drawable.candle_1 is the yellow flame image, flag is to track if flame is currently blown off or not. flag=flase means that flame is still lighting):

```
int[] smokeImages = { R.drawable.smoke_1, R.drawable.smoke_2,
        R.drawable.smoke_3, R.drawable.smoke_4, R.drawable.smoke_5,
        R.drawable.smoke_6, R.drawable.smoke_7, R.drawable.smoke_8,
        R.drawable.smoke_9, R.drawable.smoke_10, R.drawable.smoke_11,
        R.drawable.smoke_12, R.drawable.smoke_13, R.drawable.smoke_14,
        R.drawable.smoke_15, R.drawable.smoke_16, R.drawable.smoke_17,
        R.drawable.smoke_18, R.drawable.smoke_19, R.drawable.smoke_20,
        R.drawable.smoke_21 };


    this.flamImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (flag) {
                flamImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.smoke_22));
                flag = false;
                startTimer();
            } else {
                flamImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.candle_1));
                flag = true;
                smokemageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.smoke_22);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startTimer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
            smokemageView.setImageResource(smokeImages[i]);
        } catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException) {
        }
    }
    smokemageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.smoke_22);
}
```

The flame does go off and comes back on repetitive touch but I don't see proper smoke animation

Comment: It's not the anser but just a small hint. Does Android support animated gif? Perhaps it would solve your problem very easily?

Comment: setImageResource need to be called on the ui thread. use runOnUiThread or post on a handler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You could simply wrap your for statement in a while loop, set off by a boolean:**
just set the boolean to true whenever you want the drawable to animate.

```
private void startTimer() {

while (timing) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
            smokemageView.setImageResource(smokeImages[i]);
        } catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException) {
      }
    }
  }
  smokemageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.smoke_22);
}
```

**else you could create an `AnimationDrawable` object:** (probably the easier, more error-proof route)

```
AnimationDrawable anim = new AnimationDrawable();
        anim.addFrame(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smoke_1),
                250);
        anim.addFrame(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smoke_2),
                250);
        anim.addFrame(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smoke_3),
                250);
        anim.addFrame(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smoke_4),
                250);

        //......So on, so forth until you have a satisfying animation sequence


        //set ImageView to AnimatedDrawable
        smokemageView.setImageDrawable(anim);

        //if you want the animation to loop, set false
        anim.setOneShot(false);
        anim.start();
```

I sure hope this helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: AnimationDrawable is excellent and is working very well. Only once small concern, I don't any method where I can set a different transparent drawable after the animation has completed one round of execution. Any pointers pls. Edit: Oh! how can I be so dumb, I had to set the transparent image as last frame. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yep, make sure its after the draw tables are looped, then set the transparent drawable. Glad I could help, good luck!

Comment: Nice one! 1+ Which I've found this sooner

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep` is bad. Really bad.

However, I would suggest you to use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Tiny example for TimerTask:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new ImageTask(), 0, 250);

class ImageTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        // Change image here.
    }
}
```

The class `ImageTask` will be executed every 250ms. You can change your image there.

Tiny example for Handler:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Change image here.
        handler.postDelayed(this, 250);
    }
};
handler.post(r);
```

It'll solve your problem, but it's by far not the best way to do it. GreyBeardedGeek has a good alternative solution for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

While some of the other answers here will probably solve your immediate problem, this is not the best way to go about creating an animation.

The 'better' way is to use the [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) class, and let the framework do all of the work for you :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html