# Any memory efficient method to play frame animation on Android?

Tags: android

I have a requirement that asks for a looping of 100 images that are around 13kb each.  At first I tried to use AnimationDrable and load them programatically like this:

```
   public void animationPlay(){

    frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
    String index = "00000";
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if(i<10 ){
            index = "0000" + i;
        }else if(i< 100){
            index = "000" + i;
        }else if(i< 10000){
            index = "00" + i;
        }

        String finalString = "acting_10_confetti" + index;
        int frameIdentifier = getResources().getIdentifier(finalString, "drawable", getPackageName());
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(frameIdentifier), 70);

    }

    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    view.setBackground(frameAnimation);

    frameAnimation.start();
}
```

The problem is as soon as I add the 10th frame, the app crashes with Out of Memory Error.

Has anyone came across this problem before?

Comment: I am facing similar issue I and asked similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242268/most-efficient-way-to-show-frame-by-frame-animation-android I am currently experimenting with ndk and performance is good but coding is really tough I suggest you try either renderscript or ndk

Comment: I'm trying to use asynctask to load the images and then set the images as soon as it loads with a delay.

Comment: for 13 kb images you can do that I tried to make a custom image view and incorporated animation inside onDraw of canvas but it was not giving the result I wanted.

Comment: just decode one frame at a time and display the decoded Bitmap and you will avoid out of memory errors

Comment: But if I want the frames to play every 70ms, it'd be more complicated than that right? Because I need to care about performance and to meet a pretty strict timing or else the animation may look jerky or weird.